# NullPointer.Exception PopupWindow.getMaxAvailableHeight using ListPopupWindow

Tags: android, exception, adapter, popupwindow, baseadapter

I'm trying to use a PopupWindow with an adapter but this exception occurs.
I tried to search for something that solve this problem but I didn't found anything.

Here is the Exception

```
07-18 10:58:27.600: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 3% free 6409K/6595K, paused 40ms
07-18 10:58:27.600: I/dalvikvm-heap(15218): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.804MB for 513744-byte allocation
07-18 10:58:27.669: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 3% free 6902K/7111K, paused 41ms
07-18 10:58:27.749: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 6902K/7111K, paused 3ms+12ms
07-18 10:58:29.619: D/post(15218): Result from post JsonPost : 200 : {"success":false}
07-18 10:58:29.809: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 3% free 7235K/7431K, paused 3ms+2ms
07-18 10:58:30.459: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 217K, 5% free 7333K/7687K, paused 99ms
07-18 10:58:30.499: I/dalvikvm-heap(15218): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.920MB for 5981168-byte allocation
07-18 10:58:30.569: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 13174K/13575K, paused 35ms
07-18 10:58:30.649: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 13174K/13575K, paused 3ms+2ms
07-18 10:58:31.499: D/dalvikvm(15218): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6137K, 42% free 9002K/15303K, paused 3ms+3ms
07-18 10:58:59.759: D/AndroidRuntime(15218): Shutting down VM
07-18 10:58:59.759: W/dalvikvm(15218): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.getMaxAvailableHeight(PopupWindow.java:1164)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1067)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:517)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at br.com.timo.atlas.PrincipalActivity.onClick(PrincipalActivity.java:123)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-18 10:58:59.769: E/AndroidRuntime(15218):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here's my main class code

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private ListView lv_fragmentLista_Lista;
private ListView lv_fragmentLista_ListaDireita;
private ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
private View popupWindow;
private Button bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares;
private Button bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos;
private Button bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario;
private Button bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMais;
private Button bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMenos;
private GrupoMuscularAdapter gma;
private MusculoAdapter ma;
private PopupAdapter popupAdapter;

//  private final Typeface tfCabinSemiBoldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-SemiBoldItalic.ttf");
//  private final Typeface tfCabinMediumItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-MediumItalic.ttf");
//  private final Typeface tfCabinMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-Medium.ttf");
//  private final Typeface tfCabinItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-Italic.ttf");
//  private final Typeface tfCabinBoldItalic = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-BoldItalic.ttf");
//  private final Typeface tfCabinBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-Bold.ttf");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    AtlasDataBaseHelper dbHelper = new AtlasDataBaseHelper(this);

    bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares);
    bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setOnClickListener(this);

    bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos);
    bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos.setOnClickListener(this);

    bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario);
    bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario.setOnClickListener(this);

    bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMais);
    bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMais.setOnClickListener(this);

    bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMenos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMenos);
    bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMenos.setOnClickListener(this);


    List<AreaMuscular> lstAreaMuscular = dbHelper.selectAllAreaMuscular();
    gma = new GrupoMuscularAdapter(this,lstAreaMuscular);

    ma = new MusculoAdapter(this);

    List<Dicionario> lstDicionario = dbHelper.selectAllDicionario();
    popupAdapter = new PopupAdapter(this,lstDicionario);
    popupWindow = findViewById(R.layout.fragment_lista);

    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this);
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(popupWindow);
    listPopupWindow.setContentWidth(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    listPopupWindow.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    listPopupWindow.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_FROM_FOCUSABLE);
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(popupAdapter);

    lv_fragmentLista_ListaDireita = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_activity_ListaMenuDireito);
    lv_fragmentLista_ListaDireita.setAdapter(ma);

    lv_fragmentLista_Lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_activity_ListaMenuEsquerdo);
    lv_fragmentLista_Lista.setAdapter(gma);
    lv_fragmentLista_Lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mudaFundoBotao(0);
            lv_fragmentLista_Lista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lv_fragmentLista_ListaDireita.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.i("ID", id + "");
            Log.i("POSITION", position + "");
        }

    });

    setFontFace();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares){
        mudaFundoBotao(R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lv_fragmentLista_ListaDireita.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lv_fragmentLista_Lista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos){
        mudaFundoBotao(R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos);
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario){
        mudaFundoBotao(R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario);
        listPopupWindow.show();

    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMenos){

    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.bt_activityInfosPrincipal_BotaoMais){

    }

}

private void mudaFundoBotao(int idBotao){

    if(idBotao == R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares){
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_ativo);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
    }

    if(idBotao == R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos){
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_ativo);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
    }

    if(idBotao == R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario){
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_ativo);
    }

    if(idBotao == 0){
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
        bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bt_normal);
    }

}

private void setFontFace(){

    Typeface tfCabinRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-Regular.ttf");
    Typeface tfCabinSemiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-SemiBold.ttf");

    bt_activityTopBarMenu_AreaMusculares.setTypeface(tfCabinSemiBold);
    bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario.setTypeface(tfCabinRegular);
    bt_activityTopBarMenu_MeusFavoritos.setTypeface(tfCabinRegular);

}
```

}

Line 123 is the listPopupWindow.show();

I'm creating the ListPopupWindow and trying to show when I click on the button R.id.bt_activityTopBarMenu_Dicionario.

Thanks!

Comment: which line is 123 in your file?

Comment: @TalDroid - listPopupWindow.show();

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solution? And in my case, I don't know to reproduce this error. It just happen randomly with my customers and I see the ACRA log.

Comment: Sorry @Tulio. I didn't found the answer for this question but I made some changes on my project who worked for me. Now I use a LayoutInflater with a View and a PopupWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
This is not the solution for this error but it's a alternative route that I found.

First I created this variables

```
private LayoutInflater popupWindowInflaterAcoesMusculares;
private View viewPopupWindowAcoesMusculares;
private PopupWindow popupWindowAcoesMusculares;
```

Next on my onCreate method I use this code

```
popupWindowInflaterAcoesMusculares = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
viewPopupWindowAcoesMusculares = popupWindowInflaterAcoesMusculares.inflate(R.layout.content_acoes_musculares, null,true);

vp_contentAcoesMusculares_SequenciaExercicios = (ViewPager) viewPopupWindowAcoesMusculares.findViewById(R.id.vp_contentAcoesMusculares_SequenciaExercicios);
tv_contentAcoesMusculares_NomeSequencia = (TextView) viewPopupWindowAcoesMusculares.findViewById(R.id.tv_contentAcoesMusculares_NomeSequencia);
tv_contentAcoesMusculares_DescricaoSequencia = (TextView) viewPopupWindowAcoesMusculares.findViewById(R.id.tv_contentAcoesMusculares_DescricaoSequencia);

popupWindowAcoesMusculares = new PopupWindow(viewPopupWindowAcoesMusculares,400,500,true);
popupWindowAcoesMusculares.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindowAcoesMusculares.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

So I inflated my layout(content_acoes_musculares) on my View, created the widgets that I use and created my PopupWindow using the View I inflated.

And to show my PopupWindow I used this code below.

```
if(!popupWindowAcoesMusculares.isShowing()){
    int[] local = new int[2];
    bt_activityInfosPrincipal_AcoesMusculares.getLocationOnScreen(local);
    popupWindowAcoesMusculares.showAtLocation(v,Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,local[0],local[1] + 60);
}
```

I hope this help.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for posting your workaround! I think my problem cause was different than yours but you gave me an idea that ended up helping me.